# Connect to Oracle Database from SQLAlchemy in Python on AWS EC2

Tags: python, oracle, docker, amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy

I'm using python Jupyter-Lab inside a Docker Conteiner, which is embedded in an AWS EC-2. This Docker Container has an Instant Oracle Cliente installed inside it, so everything is set. The problem is that I'm still having trouble to connect this Docker to my AWS RDS with an Oracle Database, but only using SQLAlchemy.

When I try the connection using cx-Oracle==8.2.1 engine:

```
host = '***********************'
user = '*********'
password = '**********'
port = '****'
service = '****'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host,
                            port,
                            service)
engine_oracle = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=password, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Everything works fine. I can read tables using pandas `read_sql()`, I can create tables using `cx_Oracle execute()`, etc.

But when I try to take a DataFrame and send it to my RDS using pandas `to_sql()`, my cx_Oracle connection returns the error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I then tried to use a SQLAlchemy==1.4.22 engine from the string:

```
tns = """
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = %s)(PORT = %s))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = %s)
    )
  )
""" % (host, port, service)

engine_alchemy = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://%s:%s@%s' % (user, password, tns))
```

But I get this error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

And I keep getting this error even when I try to use pandas `read_sql` with the SQLAlchemy engine. Thus, I ran out of options. Can somebody help me please?

********EDIT*********

I tried again with SQLAlchemy==1.3.9 and it worked. Does anybody knows why?

The code I'm using for reading and sending a test table from and to Oracle is:

```
sql = """
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        DADOS_MIS.DR_ACIO_ATIVOS_HASH
    WHERE
        ROWNUM <= 5"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine_oracle)
dtyp1 = {c:'VARCHAR2('+str(df[c].str.len().max())+')'
         for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
dtyp2 = {c:'NUMBER'
         for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'float64'].tolist()}
dtyp3 = {c:'DATE'
         for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'datetime'].tolist()}
dtyp4 = {c:'NUMBER'
         for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'int64'].tolist()}

dtyp_total = dtyp1
dtyp_total.update(dtyp2)
dtyp_total.update(dtyp3)
dtyp_total.update(dtyp4)
df.to_sql(name='teste', con=engine_oracle, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtyp_total, index=False)
```

The `dtyp_total` is:

```
{'IDENTIFICADOR': 'VARCHAR2(32)',
 'IDENTIFICADOR_PRODUTO': 'VARCHAR2(32)',
 'DATA_CHAMADA': 'VARCHAR2(19)',
 'TABULACAO': 'VARCHAR2(25)'}
```

Comment: Try something like `oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199:1521/?service_name=xepdb1&encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Now I got the error:

`DatabaseError: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

My host is not the IP address, but the DNE. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: You will get that error if the DNS name does not resolve to a valid IP address. Check for typos.

Comment: I tried again with SQLAlchemy==1.3.9 and it worked. Do you know how to make the transition to 1.4.22? We are implementing a culture to always use the newest version.

Comment: Try with 1.4.22 using just `?service_name=whatever` at the end of the connection URI (omitting the "encoding" arguments). Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error: `DatabaseError: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

Comment: Are there any punctuation or other "strange" characters in the DNS name or the service name?

Comment: No, only "." and "-". I really have no idea what is wrong. Maybe we have a bug?

Comment: Wind back, use the latest versions, and focus on the error ORA-01036.  Share some code and table description and data so we can help there.

Comment: For reference, the SQLAlchemy connection doc for Oracle is [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-cx_oracle-connect).  (But since you can connect and query, it's moot for this specific question)

Comment: @ChristopherJones, just updated the question with the code I'm using.